# Spring @Debounce annotation design

Tags: spring, rx-java

I'm trying to design an custom Spring annotaion @Debounce like below

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Debounce {

    long deBounceMillis() default 200;
}
```

Any methods annotate with this will execute only once in specified time window.
I idea is combining Spring AOP(@Around) and RxJava features(debounce/throttleWithTimeout etc.).
Could anyone give some tips/suggestions/code ?
Thanks

Comment: activate it using scheduler and find it using reflection will by my first approach not sure if I am in right direction

Comment: @emotionlessbananas you are right ,using ScheduledExecutorService is one way, I've already implement one version with that and now I'm looking for a more fancy one.